# Comparing dates with table not immediately joinable in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

This is most likely a simple question, but I have no idea how to solve it.

In this scenario, I have three tables. Events, ads and visits. Ads and visits both have event_id fields, and visits has an ad_id field. In the end, we want to compare two event dates.

Based on the id of an ad, i need to get all visits, where their event's date is later than the ad's event date.

I would love to provide some code, but in this case I'm pretty lost, I have no idea how to do joins upon joins like that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select v.*
from ads a
join events ae on ae.id = a.event_id
join visits v on v.id = a.visit_id
join events ve on ve.id = v.event_id and ve.event_date > ae.event_date
where a.id = ?
```

The trick here is putting a condition in the `on` clause of the join to the visit's event comparing with the ad's event.

Note too that the same table can be joined more than once by assigning different table aliases.